# Categories Description: Secondary Information for Categories

Tags: e-commerce, information-architecture, categories

I want to add some secondary information in all products categories in an e-commerce website.

The text is around 4-5 paragraphs (sometimes maybe more) and it's something like a description for the category, some buying tips, explaining the differences between products, something like a user/buying guide for each different category of the website.

The question is where to put that info. So far i've come up with 3 possible scenarios:

1. Put the text in the category page itself, just above the products.
2. Put the text in a different section of the same website (Blog/Knowledge Base...)
3. Put the text in the corporate website (on a different domain of the same client)

**Scenario #1**: *the worst case scenario*. The text for some categories might be long, so the products would be pushed down the page and the user would have to scroll down.

**Scenario #2**: *the predominant scenario*. We'll take a small portion of the text and place it along with a product image in the category page, something like a small category description with a read more button that would take you to another page on the same website.

**Scenario #3**: *the just a thought scenario*. The client has 2 different domains (for the same company). He has the corporate website (company info, etc) on one domain and the e-commerce website on another. So i thought i maybe use the corporate website in order to store the info and link the 'read more' button to that website.

Answer (score 1):

Four or five paragraphs is a lot of information for an ecommerce site (unless it is very specialized and buyers need that information upfront - example you're selling elevators/elevator equipment - and the user base doesn't like "clicking").

Your second scenario is excellent and can come in a wide variety of flavors, divs that expand off to the side or cover a good portion of the screen. The divs can be "tabbed" to display more information. It all depends on your user base.

Whatever solution you select - test as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a specialised audience. They are doctors about to buy medical equipment. In some cases the category description helps them understand the products' functionalities better, the differences between them, why buy this instead of that etc.

I agree that 4-5 paragraphs is too much info for an e-commerce store, but since the client is willing to provide that type of content, i believe that it should be placed somewhere in the website for the clients that will actually need to read it (i guess, obviously, some of them will not).

The question is *where* is the most appropriate place for that kind of content and how can i connect it best with each category, so i'll keep both user groups happy: the ones who need that info and the ones who don't.

Comment: Placing them in "hidden" divs until selected seems like a good first step. You mentioned something like that in Scenario 2.